# System.Timer synchronization not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, timer, windows-services

I have created a windows service which will fire an event every T interval. This event will consume a web service and call its web method. This windows service has no idea how long will the web method take to complete the execution.

What I am seeing is when interval is over, multiple instances of web method is running.I am using counters but it is not working. I don't want overlapping of web method execution.

```
    public partial class AutoAllocation: ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer timer = null;
        private bool runningCounter=false;
        public AutoAllocation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            string timerInterval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeInterval"];
            timer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(timerInterval);
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.TimerTick);
            timer.Enabled = true;            
        }

        private void TimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (runningCounter == false)
            {
                runningCounter = true;
                EmployeeManagementService resourceMgmt = new EmployeeManagementService ();

                resourceMgmt.AutoAllocateSalary();
                runningCounter = false;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting [AutoReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx) to false.

This means the timer will fire once and won't fire again until you manually start it again, which you can do after your webservice call.

For example:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {           
        string timerInterval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeInterval"];

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(timerInterval);
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.TimerTick);
        timer.Start();          
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeeManagementService resourceMgmt = new EmployeeManagementService ();

        resourceMgmt.AutoAllocateSalary();

        ((Timer)sender).Start();
    }
```

This will stop any overlapping of calls, which is probably what's going on here.

Also remember that the interval is in *milliseconds* so if you're supplying seconds make sure its `*1000`.